# Error when running flutter app with cloned github repo

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I would like to ask if someone encountered this issue, I have tried cloning my flutter repo from github and opened my app in the root folder of the repository `flutter pub get` and after that I tried running it in an emulator however I do get this error...

[image: error code after running]

I have tried doing `fluter clean` and `fluter pub get` same with `flutter pub get` but I got no luck, this is my first time encountering this error so I really have no Idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add null check(?) in given directions where your error at

Comment: Hello, I think those are not my codes. I think it's flutter's.

Comment: My app is perfectly working in local, however if i try to pull or clone it on other pc, this errors shows.

Comment: check flutter versions in both of the PC. Or if you want to run without null safety use --no-sound-null-safety with flutter run

Answer (score 0):

You can add null (i) to the error message,and for detail you can check https://dart.dev/null-safety

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).